# how to test DAO Implementations methods in spring mvc with java configuration classes and no XML using jUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, netbeans, junit

i'm working in a spring mvc project using netbeans i created a netbeans maven web project and i configured it to be a spring mvc project with java classes configuration and NO-XML, i'm trying to do a unit test of a insert DAO implementation method and my autowired DAO variable is always null

i was following this tutorial http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles

here is my MvcConfig class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("controller")
@EnableWebMvc  
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {  




    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
       configurer.enable();
    }

    //JDBCTEMPLATE
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE");
        dataSource.setUsername("myPC");
        dataSource.setPassword("fakePassword");

        return dataSource;
    }

    //CREATE DAO BEAN 
    @Bean
    public UserDAO getUserDAO() {
        return new UserDAOImplementation( getDataSource() );
    }
}
```

here is my User DAO

```
public interface UserDAO{

    public void insertUser(User user);

}
```

and my UserDAOImplementation

```
public class UserDAOImplementation implements UserDAO{

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public UserDAOImplementation () {}

    public UserDAOImplementation (DataSource datasource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate  =  new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUser(User user) {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO User"
                   + "(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6)"
                   + " VALUES (SEQ_user.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, user.getField1(), 
                                 user.getField2(), 
                                 user.getField3(), 
                                 user.getField4(), 
                                 user.getField5() );
    }
}
```

and here is my test class i have commented "@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)" beacuse it gives me this error

```
org/junit/runners/model/MultipleFailureException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.withAfterClasses(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:187)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.classBlock(ParentRunner.java:145)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:235)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runners.model.MultipleFailureException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 16 more
```

this is my test class

```
// this is commented because it gives me errors @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@ContextConfiguration(classes=MvcConfig .class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class UserTest{

    User user;

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

@Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("@Before - setUp");


        user  =  new User();

       user.setField1("a"); 
       user.setField2("a"); 
       user.setField3("a"); 
       user.setField4("a"); 
       user.setField5("a");
    }

 @Test
public void insertUser () {

    userDAO.insertUser(user);
}
```

the AutoWired userDAO variable is always null

i'm running the test by right clicking it and choose run file 
this are the imports i'm using

```
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;
```

i'm using netbeans 8.0.2, my thoughts are that the problem is because i'm not using this `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` beacuse it gives me the errors that i mention before, but i dont know maybe i'm missing something, this insert method works fine outside the test i just wanted to test it to test some new methods in the future and i wanted to learn how to test methods with a java configuration

***EDIT***

i looked at my folder Test Depencies and inside my package org.junit.runners.model theres no a MultipleFailureException i dont know if that could be the error

***EDIT 2***
i updated my junit version from junit 4.7 to junit 4.12 and know i have this error ERROR: Failed to load  ApplicationContext

```
    Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:199)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:253)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:63)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:83)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae1586a5.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$16(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae1586a5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$38361e62.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:311)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae1586a5.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: Do you have `junit.jar` in classpath ?

Comment: since is a maven web project i dont know how to find my classpath i tried right click-> properties -> but i cant find a library option.  but i can see a junit.jar inside my Test Depencies folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution since my MvcConfig class have a `@EnableWebMvc` annotation
like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("controller")
@EnableWebMvc  
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

i needed to add this annotation to my test class `@WebAppConfiguration` and change the loader value from `AnnotationConfigContextLoader` to this `AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader` like this:

```
loader=AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class
```

so in conclusion i  modified my test class like this:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=MvcConfiguracion.class, loader=AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
public class UserTest{
```